# Warning pop-up is difficult to read

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design

The colors should be changed. I can't see what is written. That yellow and white color make it impossible to read. It can be read but you need to select the text with your cursor.

[image: warning popup]

Comment: That color contrast is quite hard to see for me as well. I'll mark this as a bug / design so that the developers can track this request. Anyone who agrees with this suggestion should upvote it so we can know it's a popular request. Thanks all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely agree - the next build (> rev 2012.8.20.3730<sup>*</sup>) will change the text color to black to increase legibility.

<sup>* this can be found in the bottom right of the page's footer</sup>